# MS Excel Average function (value1, quantity1, value2, quantity2,..)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there any function in Excel that calculates average value and takes arguments like (value1, quantity1, value2, quantity2,..)? And the function should return value of (value1*quantity1 + value2*quantity2) / (quantity1 + quantity2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not have a function that specifically calculates  a weighted average in this way. It's easy enough get there, however. If you have the values in one range, say A1:A10, and the quantities in the second, then the weighted average is SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10, B1:B10)/SUM(B1:B10).